# How to delay the response in Observable error?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular2-http

I'm making a login service in angular2 with observables, but i need a way to delay the response in error. Actually my service looks like this:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Location} from '@angular/common';
import {Headers, RequestOptions, Http} from "@angular/http";
import {Router} from '@angular/router'
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Rx";

import {Urls} from "../shared/Urls";

@Injectable()

export class LoginService {

    constructor(private http:Http, private router:Router, private location:Location) {
    }

    loginHospital(email:string, contrasena:string) {
        let url = `${Urls.urlBase + Urls.loginHospital}`;
        let body = JSON.stringify({email, contrasena});
        let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

        return this.http.post(url, body, options)
            .delay(2000) //it doesn't work :(
            .map(res => res.json())
            .map(res => {
                if (res.error) {
                    return this.handleError(res.error);
                }
                localStorage.setItem('jwt', res.data.token);
                return true;
            }).catch(this.handleError);
    }

    logout() {....}

    private handleError(error) {
        error = error.json().error;
        let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
            error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Error en el servidor >:v';
        console.error(errMsg);

        return Observable.throw(errMsg);

    }
}
```

In fact, "If the call has correct data, it doesn't be delayed. But if get a error code, any call will be delayed".

In the server side, i send a 403 code in a login error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: May I ask why you need a delay. What do you want to delay for what purpose?

Comment: Is a login service, in case that the user introduce incorrect data, I don't want that the user send a lot of calls to the api.

Comment: I see. So the first call shouldn't necessarily be delayed, only subsequent calls?

Comment: If the call has correct data, it doesn't be delayed. But if get a error code, any call be delayed. I don't know if this response your question... my english need some practice jaja.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear now. I myself don't know RxJS well enough but for others it should now be easier to answer.

Comment: I am having this exact same problem, adding in `delay(2000)` after `Http` call does nothing. I want to add a delay to simulate lag so I can check my ajax loaders are working properly. Does anyone know how to make it work?

Comment: I resolve this time ago, let me add the answer.

Comment: Sorry, i delayed the response in the server.